# Angular form to not allow field starting with space

Tags: angular

I'm trying to validate a name field with not allowing spaces in the beginning, also tried this ( [Angular Form Input block (space) REGEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53354888/angular-form-input-block-space-regex) ), but that doesn't allow spaces at all.

I have something like this:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="createEditForm.controls['nameCtrl'].hasError('required')">
    Your Name
</mat-error>
```

Also tried this ( [How to validate white spaces/empty spaces? [Angular 2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39236992/how-to-validate-white-spaces-empty-spaces-angular-2) ), but that allows the field to start with the space, just doesn't allow a empty space with not chars.

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't want to trim the string value instead of not allowing the user to enter space?

Comment: You could use a regular expression (pattern) validator.

Comment: @AlfMoh Haven't considered that, it worked! Thanks.

Comment: And you tried to remove the excess space onblur? onBlur(value) {
    this.el.value = value.trim();
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a trim validator as @AlfMoh said.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ValidatorFn, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

const trimValidator: ValidatorFn = (control: FormControl) => {
  if (control.value.startsWith(' ')) {
    return {
      'trimError': { value: 'control has leading whitespace' }
    };
  }
  if (control.value.endsWith(' ')) {
    return {
      'trimError': { value: 'control has trailing whitespace' }
    };
  }

  return null;
};

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  control = new FormControl('', trimValidator);
}
```

Worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom validator :

```js
export function whitespaceValidator(form: FormCntrol): ValidationErrors {
    return form.value.startsWith(" ") ? {whitespace: true} : null;
  }
}
```

Add it into your form declaration :

```
createEditForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  nameCtrl: new FormControl('', whitespaceValidator)
})
```

And change your html to :

```
<mat-error *ngIf="createEditForm.controls['nameCtrl'].hasError('whitespace')">
    Your Name
</mat-error>
```

Answer (score 1):

Even more simple, to avoid white spaces at the beginning and at the end with a number of characters between 3 and 250 :

```
Validators.pattern("^\\S{1}.{1,248}\\S{1}$")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Space at start is not allowed**
we can implement this in couple of steps.

**Step: 1**
Generate custom validator service  as

```
  ng generate service custom-validator
```

**Step: 2**  Filled the service with

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomValidatorService {

  static notAllowedSpaceValidator(control: FormControl) {
    let userInput = control.value;
    if (userInput && userInput.length > 0) {
      if (userInput[0] === " ") {
        return {
          forbiddenSpace: {
            value: userInput,
          },
        };
      }
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

**Step 3** we are almost done, Now we just need to use this validation as

```
businessesForm: FormGroup; // declaration

 this.businessesForm = fb.group({
      businessName: [
        "",
        [CustomValidatorService.notAllowedSpaceValidator],  // <--- to foucs
      ], 
    });
```